# HTML: Why float:left is required when children blocks width sum equals parent width

Tags: html, css

Sorry if my question is duplicate, I just could not choose the appropriate search request.

So, consider the parent `<div>` with two inline-block children, each one has `width: 50%`. If do not setup `overflow: hidden` for parent and `float: left` for children, children will not form one row inside the parent.

But why? Why 50% + 50% is not equal one full row? Why we need the float?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common scenario is because you have white spaces between the chlidren nodes:

```css
#container{
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
#container div{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The solution is to remove the whitespace:

```css
#container{
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
#container div{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div><!--
  --><div></div>
</div>
```

The second most common scenario is due to the preset `margin` usually found in browsers:

```css
#container{
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}

#container div{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 8px;  /* browser default */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div><!--
  --><div></div>
</div>
```

Override it with `margin: 0` to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Because also the spaces take place. If you don't want to use floats you have almost two choices: commenting out the spaces between html tags or setting font-size: 0px on the parent and then back on the children.